# Is there a way to justify-align floating HTML elements with CSS?

Tags: css, alignment, css-float, justify

Essentially, I'm trying to achieve the affect of "text-align:justify" but with floating block elements.  I have many  blocks that I want to justify-align.

Ie. each line is horizontally-spaced differently to make sure lengths of each line are the same.  (Non-ragged right edge).

Is there a way to do this with CSS?  If not, is there a suitable JS library to achieve this?  Or is this just infeasible?

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample of what you have done so far, or a mockup of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What are those blocks? Images? Also, do they have an equal height?

Comment: I would work if you defined display:inline-block on the blocks instead of floating them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the items are not actually `float`ing, you can use `position:absolute; left:1em; right:1em` to have CSS calculate the widths of the items for you based on offsets from some positioned parent.

If you are only using `float` because you have some block-level items you are trying to make flow, use `display:inline-block` on the items instead of floating them. If the parent element has `text-align:justify` this should give you the effect (I imagine that) you want.

Here is a [simple test](http://jsfiddle.net/mfmfR/1/) showing you the result of `inline-block` with `text-align:justify`.

**Edit**: I've updated the simple test to more clearly show that the left and right edges are always aligned except for the last line.

Comment: that is the intended effect, but it doesn't work in IE7.  I've modified it for IE7 (http://jsfiddle.net/mfmfR/3/), and I think this may be the answer I'm looking for.  I'll have to double check that this actually works for my existing code.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: this is working, but there is a little proble: the last line does not align, is there a solution for this, like full justify?

Comment: @BotondVajna You can create full-justification by adding `#wrap:after {content:""; display:inline-block; width:100%}`. Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfmfR/527/).

Answer (score 1):

Completing previous answer, if you want to align DOM nodes created programatically (e.g. by using document.createElement and parentElement.appendChild in javaScript), no white space will be added between aligned elements. This can cause non-working of aligment.

On my Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 and Firefox 51.0.1 (64-bit) browsers, aligment doesn't work if there aren't any white spaces to separate `div` elements:

https://jsfiddle.net/jc5qwyaw/

There is an example when I create DOM nodes by javaScript:

https://jsfiddle.net/oa8yeudr/

If you uncomment command `wrapDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));`, you can see the difference.
Possible solution can be appending a white space text node after div nodes as example shows above.

Only tested on Chrome 56.0.2924.87 and Firefox 51.0.1 (64-bit).